# How can I prevent Facebook from considering Google drive links unsafe on my website?

Tags: google, security, images, facebook, cdn

On my small website I've recently began using Google Drive as content delivery network.  This is to solve resource usage issues with my provider.

This worked well, but I'm confused because Facebook is considering my pages unsafe and delivering a warning because of the link to images stored on Google drive.

Looking for answers on this issues, I found this [linkclaiming Facebook blocks links to Google plus pages](https://plus.google.com/+MikeElgan/posts/hU2Gh9fDwV9)  for its own reasons. I haven't found further informations. That link is dated back to 2012, if this is the reason, is it be still up to date? Is this ordinary?

I did use the Facebook form provided to notify possible cases of false warnings, but got no answers.

Comment: Google drive is NOT a content delivery network.  A CDN moves data close to users and serves it quickly.  Google drive is not likely to be speedy hosting.  Your use of Google Drive is third party image hosting (non-CDN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook in general doesn't like to send users out of it, that's why it makes it difficult for the users to leave.

I've had that problem in the past, then stopped, then had it again, there seems to be no reason for this.

I think Facebook handles the same links differently. For example sharing a link inside a group is not the same as sharing it on a wall or on a Friend's page, so once again, very unpredictable.

If you were sharing always the same link, as your fans / friends follow it and mark it as safe, the warning disappears. If it's not the case, the warning will remain.

For the purpose, here's a guy that thinks he has a [solution](https://plus.google.com/+MikeElgan/posts/hU2Gh9fDwV9), not that it works.

For what it counts, you shouldn't be using Google Drive as a CDN, because well, it's not a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use redirection link. You can generate a link to your Google Drive using:

- [**http://redirector.ml**](http://redirector.ml) (online javascript redirection tool).